# Could I use my Xbox 360 disk of minecraft to play on Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-360, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

I have had an Xbox 360 disk of Minecraft for a while. Could I use it on the Xbox One?

Answer (score 2):

No you can’t. Xbox 360 Minecraft discs can only be played on 360 as is the same with Xbox one. For the full list of backwards compatible games look here.

https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2019-04-10-xbox-one-backwards-compatibility-list-xbox-360-games-6011